# Application of mixed-effects model for unbalanced sample size and repeated measures

Tags: r, mixed-model, predictive-models

In my experimental design I have 4 treatments, 3 replicates per treatment and 3 blocks. In each plot I measured whether a plant is infested or not ("Infestate" variable). This measure has been performed to 30 to 40 plants placed at the centre of the plot. Sampling has been performed weekly (variable "Data_rilievo) on the same plants, even though the sample size might vary if some plants die. Treatment does not influence plant death. Thus, I removed from the dataset the observations resulted in plant death.

I obtained the following dataset

```
'data.frame':   2937 obs. of  15 variables:
 $ ID_pianta                : chr  "_Pianta_1" "_Pianta_2" "_Pianta_3" "_Pianta_4" ...
 $ Data_rilievo             : POSIXct, format: "2023-11-14" "2023-11-14" "2023-11-14" ...
 $ Blocco                   : num  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Trattamento              : chr  "Controllo" "Controllo" "Controllo" "Controllo" ...
 $ Infestate                : num  1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 ...
```

I opted for a mixed-effect model with treatment as fixed effect, plant ID ("ID_pianta) as random effect to account for repeated measures, and block ("Blocco") as random effect.

And this is the result

```
> summary(model)
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: Infestate ~ Trattamento + (1 | ID_pianta) + (1 | Blocco)
   Data: data

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  3835.8   3871.7  -1911.9   3823.8     2931 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.1969 -1.0611  0.6139  0.8091  1.5079 

Random effects:
 Groups    Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 ID_pianta (Intercept) 0.16880  0.4108  
 Blocco    (Intercept) 0.09686  0.3112  
Number of obs: 2937, groups:  ID_pianta, 40; Blocco, 3

Fixed effects:
                     Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)           0.59808    0.20650   2.896 0.003776 ** 
TrattamentoLavanda   -0.16521    0.11116  -1.486 0.137218    
TrattamentoRosmarino -0.02389    0.11000  -0.217 0.828075    
TrattamentoTimo      -0.37733    0.11017  -3.425 0.000615 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) TrttmL TrttmR
TrttmntLvnd -0.266              
TrttmntRsmr -0.269  0.502       
TrattamntTm -0.269  0.499  0.504
```

From what I see the only statistically significant difference is the "Timo" treatment. Can I have further information about how to interpret the results?
Is there any suggested diagnostic test may I implement to check the "validity" of my model?

Edit 19/02/2024:

Following suggestions, I have used the package `Dharma` using the following code:

```
# Simulate standardized residuals
simulated_residuals <- simulateResiduals(model)
# Plot diagnostic plots
plot(simulated_residuals)
```

This is what I get

[image: Residual analysis]

How to interpret this figure?

I wanted also to check the predictive abilities. I used this code

```
library(caret)
data$Infestate <- factor(data$Infestate, levels = c(0, 1))


# Convert predicted probabilities to binary predictions using a threshold
binary_predictions <- ifelse(predicted_probabilities > 0.5, 1, 0)

# Convert binary_predictions to a factor with levels 0 and 1
binary_predictions <- factor(binary_predictions, levels = c(0, 1))

# Create a confusion matrix
conf_matrix <- confusionMatrix(data$Infestate, binary_predictions)
print(conf_matrix)
```

And these are the results:

```
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction    0    1
         0 1811   28
         1  751   55
                                          
               Accuracy : 0.7055          
                 95% CI : (0.6877, 0.7228)
    No Information Rate : 0.9686          
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 1               
                                          
                  Kappa : 0.0709          
                                          
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : <2e-16          
                                          
            Sensitivity : 0.70687         
            Specificity : 0.66265         
         Pos Pred Value : 0.98477         
         Neg Pred Value : 0.06824         
             Prevalence : 0.96862         
         Detection Rate : 0.68469         
   Detection Prevalence : 0.69527         
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.68476         
                                          
       'Positive' Class : 0
```

It seems te model is good in predicting negative but it predicts 751 false positive. How to deal this aspect? Can the model be considered a good predictor? How can I increase predictive abilities?

Comment: For checking your model have a look at [`DHARMa`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/vignettes/DHARMa.html).